# Check if column starts with non integer

Tags: mysql, regex, case, sql-like

I am trying to see if the column value starts without a integer. The column is suppose to be 8 digits, and is Integer. I have one value which starts with letters, and I can't for some reason pick out the row with it. I'm trying to set that value to just a empty blank but that row isn't getting extracted out.

I've tried using LIKE, and REGEXP but they aren't working or the way I'm using it is failing.

EDIT: I get an exception Can't parse SQL Query when I use REGEXP. When I cast as int it gives a data conversion error cause the value starts with letters.

Example 1:

```
CASE 
WHEN Column LIKE '^[0-9]' THEN Column = ''
END
```

Example 2:

```
CASE 
WHEN Column REGEXP '^[0-9]' THEN Column = ''
END
```

Comment: LIKE doesn't use regex operators so the first should fail

Comment: REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';

Comment: Alternatively, how about usnig `CAST` so that you cast the data type to `unsigned` and it will force output of the column to  be integer, if it begins with numbers it will be null or zero (I'm not sure which hence this is just a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Just to convert the values that doesn't start with a number to a emptystring during your select you can use:

```
CASE 
  WHEN Column REGEXP '^[0-9]' THEN Column ELSE ''
END
```